# debian -bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: exec format error

Tags: c++, eclipse, debian-jessie, ubuntu-16.10

I am compiling a c++ program using Eclipse in Ubuntu 16.10. When I try to run the executable file in my beaglebone black with OS debian 8.7 jessie the system gives me the following error:
  -bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: Cross site dupe: https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error.

Comment: @Ron this is a different question, you can see it in the different environment. I have tried all the solutions that are posted in that link and I still having the same problem

Comment: Can you post the output of `file ./program`?